# Absolutely continuous probability measures example

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, examples-counterexamples

I was given the following definition:

[image]

Then this example:

[image]

It is said that $\mathbb P_1\ll\mathbb P_2$ , but I don't really see it.Please help.

Comment: You don't need to write $<<$; you can instead write $\ll$, and I changed it.  I also changed $P_1$ to $\mathbb P_1$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb{P}_{2}$ is only $0$ on the empty set but $\mathbb{P}_{1}$ also satisfies this.

Comment: AH yes, thanks alot, I was a retard.

Comment: You're welcome. Not at all, you are learning. Learning takes time.

Comment: Also, careful with the word "retard". Some people (not me, but some other) don't like when it's used that way.

Comment: Ok I will try to use more polite word next time. That is my bad habit I get from undergrad.